# Docker download layers sequentially

Tags: docker, docker-machine

is there a way to make docker download the layers of an image sequentially instead of in parallel. I require this due to our repository being very strict (or dodgey) on networking issues. I get a lot of the EOF errors like:

```
time="2016-06-14T13:15:52.936846635Z" level=debug msg="Error contacting registry http://repo.server/v1/: Get http://repo.server/v1/images/b6...be/layer: EOF"
time="2016-06-14T13:15:52.936924310Z" level=error msg="Download failed: Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (b6...be)"
```

This is when running Docker 1.11.2 on windows.

But on a Centos7 VM it all works fine with the default 1.9.1.

I noticed one difference was that 1.9.1 does the downloads sequentially. So I tried to install 1.9.1 on windows, but the quick start terminal automatically downloaded and installed the 1.11.2 version of the boot2docker ISO.

So is there some arg, config, or environment variable I can set to make docker download the layers one at a time?

Or am I jumping to the wrong conclusion assuming the concurrent downloads are causing my network errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that there was recently added a `max-concurrent-downloads` option to the configuration of the docker daemon. Here is the link to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) although I did not have a chance to test it yet myself.

Comment: Unfortunately my docker version (back on 1.11.2) is not accepting that argument. When I specify it in in the docker pull command line or the boot2docker/profile it fails with `flag provided but not defined: --max-concurrent-downloads` and much the same thing if I put it in daemon.json `unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: max-concurrent-downloads`

Comment: Ahh, seems they were added on the most recent version, 1.12.0-RC2. Guess I'll give that a go

Comment: Yeah I just saw it was recently in May discussed on GitHub so I was not sure whether it made it yet into the stable branch.